# Animated text animates in wrong order

Tags: css, html, animation, animate.css

I am using animate.css in order to animate text on page load. I am delaying the effects but it is showing the text then animating it see?

You can see the animation in action here: https://gyazo.com/a51b4248203c72cbf81012e7f7fad112.

If you need to closer to my HTML & CSS: https://hastebin.com/dawawecuvi.xml

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico');

.logotext{
    color: limegreen;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}

.navbar-default{
    background-color: dimgrey !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px limegreen !important;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
color: white !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: white !important;
}

li{
    font-size: 20px;
    
}

.navbar-right{
    padding-right: 80px;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:before {
    background: limegreen ;
}


.container-fluid { 
  padding: 0px;
}

.aboutmediv{
    background-color: black;
    height: 900px;
}

.imagetextbig { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 240px; 
    width: 100%;
    color: goldenrod;
    font-size: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    animation: slideInLeft 1s;
    animation-delay: 0.9s;
}

.navbar-fixed-top{
    animation: slideInDown 1s;
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.imgtext2{
    margin-top: 100px;
    animation: slideInRight 1s;
    animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="author" content="Nydigov">
    <meta name="description" content="Nydigovs portfolio site. Check out my recent work!">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Fellex,Nydigov,NY,nydigov,fellex,fell,fellex.me,Fellex.me">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/athyslogo.png">
    <title>Nydigov</title>
    
    <!--All links secure-->
    
    <!--Latest compiled and minified CSS--> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--Secure link to paper bootstrap theme -->   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/paper/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-I3UMl9KZhtYWd8htMkmvi+cG4KsfRMyoiX7O3teTUiqrP+34X3fuqYI5GUOC0N82" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!--Animate.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" integrity="sha384-OHBBOqpYHNsIqQy8hL1U+8OXf9hH6QRxi0+EODezv82DfnZoV7qoHAZDwMwEJvSw" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!--FontAwesome-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!--Hover CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hover.css/2.1.1/css/hover-min.css" integrity="sha384-VTeRBIyCP1UOtJsYqkdWx9FnCcVTZlBzNKjt0R0FMPZUVvNmz2bflo5bg7kbZDU1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!--Main Stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    
</head>
<body>
   <!--Navbar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><p class="logotext">Nydigov</p></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right navbar-right">
              <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#">Past Work</a></li>
              <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
    
    <!--Content-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <!--Image-->
        <div class="image">
            <img src="images/imagebacktop.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive mainimg">
            <h2 class="imagetextbig">Hi, I'm Nydigov</h2>
            <h2 class="imagetextbig imgtext2">And this is my site</h2>
        </div>
        <!--About Me-->
        <div class="aboutmediv"></div>
        
        
    </div>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, the text is animating on page load, you are answering yourself

Comment: Set the text to visibility hidden, then when the page loads make it visible

Comment: How would I do that master john?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your CSS, I presume these are the two elements we're talking about:

```
.imagetextbig { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 240px; 
    width: 100%;
    color: goldenrod;
    font-size: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    animation: slideInLeft 1s;
    animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
.imgtext2{
    margin-top: 100px;
    animation: slideInRight 1s;
    animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
```

If you want them hidden at first and then to slide in from the sides of the page, you have two options. The first option is to change the CSS so they start off-screen and animate on-screen. But there isn't a plug-and-play solution for that where you can just use the animate.css animation out of the box and have it work.

So we can do the second option, which is to hide them as the page is loaded, then have them appear when the animation starts. Use `visibility: hidden` in your default styles for the elements to hide them when the page first loads.

```
.imagetextbig { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 240px; 
    width: 100%;
    color: goldenrod;
    font-size: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    animation: slideInLeft 1s;
    animation-delay: 0.9s;
    visibility: hidden; /*add this*/
}
.imgtext2{
    margin-top: 100px;
    animation: slideInRight 1s;
    animation-delay: 0.9s;
    visibility: hidden; /*add this*/
}
```

Then, in the animation, we want to make sure they switch to `visibility: visible`, otherwise you'll be animating an invisible element.

If we go to the [animate.css website](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) and check their source code, we can see that the animation for slideInLeft looks like this:

```
@keyframes slideInLeft {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
        visibility: visible;
    }

    to {
        transform: translateZ(0);
    }
}
```

In other words, setting the elements to visible at the start of the animation is already taken care of for you. So just adding `visibility: hidden` to the default styles at the start is all you need. The slideInRight animation is similar to the slideInLeft one: it also sets `visibility: visible` at its start. So nothing to worry about there either.